# How to auto click to link on mobile( submit button)

Tags: jquery

Like a title. I want to write a script which can auto click to submit button( ON MOBILE DEVICES).

I use:

```
$("#submitbutton").click()
```

but it's not working. `#submitbutton` is ID of submit button.

Comment: "*but it's working*" ???

Comment: buddy, you need to be clear enough to question to get your expected and accurate result.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this instead:

```
$("#submitbutton").trigger('click');
```

Comment: how about other event?

Comment: try `$("#submitbutton").trigger('tap');`

Comment: $("#submitbutton").trigger('click'); is working now. But it has # character in URL.
Please help me check it: francetravelplanner.phplang.info , after click. It has /#/ in URL, i dont want to have it

Comment: Check on Mobile.Please!